# Arabic tagging using stanford pos tagger

Tags: java, arabic, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I am totally new to the world of NLP ,i need your help to get started in tagging arabic sentences using pretty Stanford pos tagger .

I have installed a full version which contains two arabic trained taggers.

please, guid me to apply this tagger in arabic using java and eclipse ,

1. what should i import?
2. what should i add to models
3. which functions and libraries to deal with arabic
4. can this tagger give correct tags even if it is not in trained set.

Actually , i have navigated the Stanford official website but it was not so helpful

Thank you in advance

Comment: How it turned out for you? did you manage to get POS from arabic?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link from where you can download Stanford parser: [nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml)

I hope you have already working Java environment. So go in the directory where you have put the parser files.

```
java -mx200m edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -retainTMPSubcategories -outputFormat "wordsAndTags,penn,typedDependencies" englishPCFG.ser.gz mumbai.txt
```

mumbai.txt is the input file.

But I found berkeley parse better. You can download from https://code.google.com/p/berkeleyparser/downloads/list

Download parser jar file and gramar for Arabic text.

Then execute simple command:

```
java -jar BerkeleyParser-1.7gr eng_sm6.gr
```

Now enter any sentence that you want to parse.

For POS, you can get downloads from http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml

Comment: @SalySa: You should explore the links, procedure is same. parser itself will give you POS. You have to apply little efforts!